# Linear algebra: Considering an affine map and formulating a conjecture

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Consider an affine map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $f(x) = Mx + s$ and let $S$ be a square. Formulate, and prove, a conjecture that relates how $\text{area}(f(S))$ depends on $\text{area}(S)$ in terms of parameters $M$ and $s$ of $f$.

Recommendations on how I should go about this?

Comment: are $s$ and $S$ both supposed to be $S$?

Comment: Hm, this is exactly how I am reading the question. Would it make sense that "s" is strictly defined in the affine function and "S" as strictly defined as a Square?

Comment: This is how I read the problem: We have some set $S$ in the plane which forms a square (in the typical geometric sense). We have a function that moves points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to (potentially) different points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now, if we take every point in $S$ and run it through $f$ we get a new set of points,  and we call this $f(S)$. This would mean that $M \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 1}$. Does this sound right?

Comment: That does sound right. Do you suggest any edits?

Comment: The only thing I might suggest is replacing linear programming with the more appropriate linear algebra tag. Linear programming is typically used to describe minimization/maximization problems with linear objective functions.

Comment: Things to think about:

 - What does adding $s$ actually do to the shape? 
 - What type of shape do we end up with after applying the linear transformation induced by matrix $M$?
 - What happens if $S$ is the unit square? Consider what happens to the corners.

Comment: Hint: Try first with diagonal matrix and  $s=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We describe the square $ABCD$ by a position vector to a corner $p=OA$ and two side vectors $a=AB$ and $b=AD$ each of length $L$.

Then
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{area}{area}
\area(S) = \det(a,b) \\
S = \{ x = p + u a + v b \mid u,v \in [0, 1] \} \quad (*)
$$
and
\begin{align}
f(S) 
&= \{ f(x) \mid x \in S \} \\
&= \{ f(p + u a + v b) \mid u, v \in [0, 1] \} \\
&= \{ M(p + u a + v b) + s \mid u, v \in [0,1] \} \\
&= \{ (Mp+s) + u (Ma) + v (Mb) \mid u,v \in [0,1] \} \\
&= \{ p' + u a' + v b' \mid u, v \in [0,1] \} 
\end{align}
we notice that $f(S)$ is of form $(*)$.

Up to here it plays no role if $M$ is a scalar or a $2\times 2$ matrix.

The $S$ in $(*)$ in general is a parallelogram. We need the additional condition $a \perp b$ to make it a rectangle and 
$\lVert a \rVert = \lVert b \rVert$ to get a square.

$S' = f(S)$ is a parallelogram with position vector $p' = M p + s$ and sides $a'= M a$ and $b' = M b$. Depending on the matrix $M$ it might degenerate to a line segment or a single point.

For scalar $M$ we would have
$$
\area(f(S))
= \det(M a, M b) = M^2 \det(a, b) = M^2 \area(S)
$$

For the matrix case it would be
\begin{align}
\area(f(S)) 
&= \det(M a, M b) \\
&= (m_{11} a_1 + m_{12} a_2)(m_{21} b_1 + m_{22} b_2) 
- (m_{21} a_1 + m_{22} a_2)(m_{11} b_1 + m_{12} b_2) \\
&= (m_{11} m_{22} - m_{21} m_{12}) a_1 b_2 +
 (m_{12} m_{21} - m_{22} m_{11}) a_2 b_1 \\
&= \det M \det(a,b) \\
&= \det M \area(S)
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Very explicit hint:

Let's do it in a simpler case.

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ affine map ($f(x)=ax+b$), same question.

$$\text{Vol}(f(S))=\int_{f(S)} 1 = \int_S |f'| = |a|\int_S 1  = |a|\text{Vol}(S) $$